# Material ui expansion panel can't click custom buttons within it

Tags: angular, angular-material, z-index, pointer-events, mat-expansion-panel

Within a `<mat-expansion-panel>`'s description I have 3 icons acting as buttons. The icons are displayed but they can not be clicked, basically they are under the expansion panel. `z-index` approaches don't work. A solution that I found was to give the icon-buttons this property `pointer-events: visiblefill !important;`. Although the icons can be clicked by using this property, every time I click one of them it will also expand the panel.

P.S. I also have these global properties to restrict the expansion only by using the arrow button:

```
span.mat-expansion-indicator {
  pointer-events: visiblefill !important;
}

mat-expansion-panel-header {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Please, show how you are using the mat-expansion

Answer (score 0):

It appears this does the trick:

```
function(event: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // Do what you want
  }
```